# How to define function by parts using SymPy library?

Tags: python, function, math, sympy

I'm beginner using sympy library so I can't execute simple operations yet.

So, said this, my problem is something like this:

[image: n]

Where x and c are symbolical values.

How can I make this kind of function? In math it's defined as function by parts. I could make this separately, and calculing the function in a range values for x/c between [0,1], but in the next step of this problem, I need to take the derivative of this function, so I relly need the function in the symbolical form.

[image]

In a first tentative, I tried to make the function using the def() build-in operator. The first part works well, but the sympy appear doesn't accept the created function when I try to take the derivative using sympy.diff.

How can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Piecewise` is designed for this. Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction:

```
>>> from sympy import Piecewise
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> z = Piecewise((x, (x > 0) & (x < 1)), (x**2, (x >= 1) & (x < 2)))
>>> z.diff(x)
Piecewise((1, (x > 0) & (x < 1)), (2*x, (x >= 1) & (x < 2)))
```

To get help on `Piecewise` just type `help(Piecewise)` in an interpreter.